# Show that the sequence $1+1/\sqrt{2}+1/\sqrt{3}+...+1/\sqrt{n}$ is unbounded

Tags: real-analysis

I need to show that $1+1/\sqrt{2}+1/\sqrt{3}+...+1/\sqrt{n}$ is unbounded. So I can show that for $S_n=1+1/2=1/3+....+1/n$, $a_n > S_n$, and $S_n$ is not bounded above, but how do I show that $a_n$ is not bounded below?

Comment: Well, it's clearly increasing but that isn't really enough.  1/root(n) > 1/n and it's a very famous result that 1 + 1/2 + 1/3  + ... is unbounded so 1/1 + 1/root(2) + .... is too.

Comment: But $(a_n)$ **is** "bounded below" (whatever that means), for example $a_n\ge1$ for every $n\ge1$.

Answer (score 5):

Here's another proof:

$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=0}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt{i}}$ is the average value of the set $\{1,\ldots,\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\}$. The average value of a set is always bigger than its smallest element, so we get
$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=0}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt{i}}\geq\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$$

Multiplying both sides by $n$ tells us that $\sum_{i=0}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt{i}}\geq\sqrt{n}$ which diverges.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** $$\left(\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{i}}\right)^2> \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{i}$$ (If you do not wish to use [integral test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence), that is.)

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Compare the sequence with
$$S_n = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k} $$

Comment: So I can show that $a_n > S_n$, and $S_n$ is not bounded above, but how do I show that $a_n$ is not bounded below?

Comment: Each term of your series is larger than the corresponding term of this one. This your sum is bigger. This sum diverges, so your sum diverges

Answer (score 2):

$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac1{\sqrt{k}}
\ge \sum_{k=1}^n \frac1{\sqrt{n}}
=\frac{n}{\sqrt{n}}
=\sqrt{n}
$.

More generally,
if $a < 1$,
$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac1{k^a}
\ge \sum_{k=1}^n \frac1{n^a}
=\frac{n}{n^a}
=n^{1-a}
\to \infty
$.

Comment: As already mentioned by user @Stella.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $$1+\dfrac1{\sqrt{2}}+\dfrac1{\sqrt{3}}+…+\dfrac1{\sqrt{n}}\gt\sqrt{n}$$ Then $$1+\dfrac1{\sqrt{2}}+\dfrac1{\sqrt{3}}+…+\dfrac1{\sqrt{n}}+\dfrac1{\sqrt{n+1}}\gt\sqrt{n}+\dfrac1{\sqrt{n+1}}\gt\sqrt{n+1}.$$ Hence by Mathematical Induction.....

Comment: This answer is pretty slick. I like it.

Comment: No induction needed.

Comment: I find the last equality nonobvious

Comment: @StellaBiderman: It depends on the person.

Comment: @Nilan Well yes. I was just informing you that this person thought so. On second pass, I do see it quite quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach. Observe that 
$$
\frac1{\sqrt{x}}\leq \frac1{\sqrt{k}},\qquad x\in [k,k+1],\quad k=1,2,3,\cdots.
$$
Integrating both sides from $x=k$ to $x=k+1$ gives
$$
\int_k^{k+1}\frac1{\sqrt{x}}\:dx\leq \frac1{\sqrt{k}}=\int_k^{k+1}\frac1{\sqrt{k}}\:dx
$$ then summing gives
$$
\int_1^{n}\frac1{\sqrt{x}}\:dx\leq 1+\dfrac1{\sqrt{2}}+\dfrac1{\sqrt{3}}+…+\dfrac1{\sqrt{n}}
$$ evaluating the left hand side 
$$
2\sqrt{n}-2\leq 1+\dfrac1{\sqrt{2}}+\dfrac1{\sqrt{3}}+…+\dfrac1{\sqrt{n}}
$$ and letting $n \to \infty$ leads to the announced result.

Answer (score 1):

$S_2=1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} >\frac{2}{\sqrt{2}}$

$S_3 = 1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} > \frac{3}{\sqrt{3}}$

$\vdots$

$S_N > \frac{N}{\sqrt{N}} = \sqrt{N} \to \infty$ as $N \to \infty$

Comment: As already mentioned by user @Stella.

Answer (score 1):

A really twisted form using Cesaro-Stolz:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1+1/\sqrt{2}+1/\sqrt{3}+...+1/\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt n}=
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1/\sqrt{n+1}}{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt n} =
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n+1}} = 2.
$$